# ¿Como solucionar este error TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer?

Tags: python

El error que me salta es:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/ej1glob.py", line 9, in 
> for i in range (alum): TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Este es mi programa:

```
print("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos")
alum=input()
for i in range (alum):
    print("Ingrese el legajo del alumno")
    leg=input()
    if leg>0:
        for P in range (5):
            print("Ingrese la nota del parcial numero ",P)
            n=input()
            if n>5:
                cp=cp+1
            else:
                print("Examen desaprobado no se toma en cuenta")
    else:
        print("El legajo ingresado es erroneo")
        leg=input("------ Ingrese el legajo nuevamente: ")

    if cp>=4:
            print("El alumno quedo regular")
    elif cp==3:
            print("El alumno quedo en estado de recuperatorio")
    else:
            print("El alumno quedo en estado de recursante")
```

Comment: `alum=int(input())` Así lo ingresado se convierte de string a entero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Lo devuelto por la función input SIEMPRE será una cadena. Y por supuesto, no puedes crear un rango a partir de una cadena.

Si quieres que sea un número entero, deberás convertir lo devuelto con dicha función a entero con int, sea o no con una validación de por medio (ver el final de la respuesta).

#### Solución

```
leg=int(input())
```

Lo que hace esta linea es convertir el resultado de input a entero.

*Nota* Si lo escrito por el usuario no se puede convertir a numero entero, por ejemplo que ingrese `abc123` o `12.5`, ocurrirá un error en el programa. Si quieres evitar esto, tendrás que validar que lo escrito por el usuario se pueda convertir. Y si no se puede, pedirle nuevamente el dato.

#### Edición

Viendo mejor tu código, creo que deberías de aplicar este concepto en todos los casos donde le pides un número al usuario.

Comment: Graciaaas, si me funciono.
No sabia eso soy nuevo en esto de python